# MySQL Join Group By and Group Concat

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I am keeping track of users connecting to a web app and leaving questions in a question feed

#### Users

```
id  name
---------
1   Jim
2   Joe
```

Because users can connect to the app from various browsers and have multiple connections, I track user connections with the use of a Token table:

#### Tokens

```
id  userid
----------
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
```

Then users asks questions:

#### Questions

```
id  userid  pageno text
------------------------------------------------
1   1       1      'Whats going on here?'
2   1       2      'How are you?'
4   2       2      'Good and you?'
```

My aim would be to output the following

```
username  questions                               Questions Page 1        Questions Page 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jim       'Whats going on here?', 'How are you?'  'Whats going on here?'  'How are you?'
Joe       'Good and you?'                                                 'Good and you?'
```

Now i tried querying the users table directly but as there are a lot of users in my db, i need to query the token table instead of the user one for performance then grouping by userid as one user can obtain many tokens.

Although now that I group by userid i am not sure how i can group concat the different questions.
See the query:

```
SELECT  u.id, u.name, q.text
FROM token t
LEFT JOIN user as u ON t.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN question as q ON t.userid = q.userid
GROUP BY t.userid
```

My problem is I only get the first question, I have tried to group concat with no luck though.

Forgot to add that it would be great if this can be dynamically done as the page number is subject to vary quite dramatically
Would you be able to help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After trying this `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT q.text) as question FROM` What are you getting?

```
SELECT  u.id, u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT q.text) as question
FROM token t
LEFT JOIN user as u ON t.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN question as q ON t.userid = q.userid
GROUP BY t.userid
```

Comment: @Sdev This is working fine on my localhost. i have tried.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I have edited the post though as I have missed part of the original problem which is filtering per pageno

Comment: @SDev What is `Question Page 1    Question Page 2`?

Comment: do you want `Question Page 1 Question Page 2?` as column header?

Comment: I've edited the post for more clarity.
The column headers are not that important,
what i cannot achieve is querying the questions per page number as part of my query

Answer (score 0):

The **query** should be like this:

```
SELECT temp.*, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(q.text) FROM questions q WHERE q.pageno = temp.pageno) as Pagewiseqtn FROM (SELECT  u.id, u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT q.text) as question, q.pageno
FROM tokens t
LEFT JOIN users as u ON t.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN questions as q ON t.userid = q.userid
GROUP BY t.userid) as temp
```

**Output:**

[image: PagewiseQuestionConcat]

Comment: Thanks Rick, but I am not sure this is the right data output: In this example Jim has asked 'How are you?' on page 2 but it appears on the second row which is Joe's row

Comment: @SDev i think it can be achieved by coding

Answer (score 0):

The most easy to understand and simple way to get the exact result as asked by OP is to divide the problem into a number of sub-queries instead of a single query.

I have created a number of intermediate `VIEW` to get the final result. Also the benefit of using intermediate `VIEW` and not intermediate `TABLE` is that any update in the original table also results in update of the results in `VIEW`

**Sub-query 1:**

```
CREATE VIEW q AS
    -> SELECT userid,  
    -> GROUP_CONCAT(text ORDER BY userid SEPARATOR ", ") AS questions
    -> FROM Questions
    -> GROUP BY userid;
    
SELECT * FROM q;
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| userid | questions                              |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
|      1 | 'How are you?', 'Whats going on here?' |
|      2 | 'Good and you?'                        |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
```

**Sub-query 2:**

```
CREATE VIEW q1 AS
    -> SELECT userid, text AS questions1
    -> FROM Questions
    -> WHERE pageno = 1;

SELECT * FROM q1;
+--------+------------------------+
| userid | questions1             |
+--------+------------------------+
|      1 | 'Whats going on here?' |
+--------+------------------------+
```

**Sub-query 3:**

```
CREATE VIEW q2 AS
    -> SELECT userid, text AS questions2
    -> FROM Questions
    -> WHERE pageno = 2;
    
SELECT * FROM q2;
+--------+-----------------+
| userid | questions2      |
+--------+-----------------+
|      1 | 'How are you?'  |
|      2 | 'Good and you?' |
+--------+-----------------+
```

**Sub-query 4:**

```
CREATE VIEW ql AS
    -> SELECT u.id, q.questions
    -> FROM Users AS u
    -> LEFT OUTER JOIN
    -> q ON u.id = q.userid;
    
SELECT * FROM ql;
+----+----------------------------------------+
| id | questions                              |
+----+----------------------------------------+
|  1 | 'How are you?', 'Whats going on here?' |
|  2 | 'Good and you?'                        |
+----+----------------------------------------+
```

**Sub-query 5:**

```
CREATE VIEW q1l AS
    -> SELECT u.id, q1.questions1
    -> FROM Users AS u
    -> LEFT OUTER JOIN
    -> q1 ON u.id = q1.userid;

SELECT * FROM q1l;
+----+------------------------+
| id | questions1             |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 | 'Whats going on here?' |
|  2 | NULL                   |
+----+------------------------+
```

**Sub-query 6:**

```
CREATE VIEW q2l AS
    -> SELECT u.id, q2.questions2
    -> FROM Users AS u
    -> LEFT OUTER JOIN
    -> q2 ON u.id = q2.userid;

SELECT * FROM q2l;
+----+-----------------+
| id | questions2      |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | 'How are you?'  |
|  2 | 'Good and you?' |
+----+-----------------+
```

**Sub-query 7:**

```
CREATE VIEW vt AS
    -> SELECT u.name, 
    -> ql.questions, 
    -> q1l.questions1, 
    -> q2l.questions2
    -> FROM 
    -> Users AS u
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> ql ON u.id = ql.id
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> q1l ON ql.id = q1l.id
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> q2l ON q1l.id = q2l.id;
    
SELECT * FROM vt;
+------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------+
| name | questions                              | questions1             | questions2      |
+------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------+
| Jim  | 'How are you?', 'Whats going on here?' | 'Whats going on here?' | 'How are you?'  |
| Joe  | 'Good and you?'                        | NULL                   | 'Good and you?' |
+------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------+
```

**Final query:**

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
    -> SELECT name AS username,
    -> COALESCE(questions, "") AS questions,
    -> COALESCE(questions1, "") AS "Questions Page 1",
    -> COALESCE(questions2, "") AS "Questions Page 2"
    -> FROM vt;
    
SELECT * FROM v;
+----------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| username | questions                              | Questions Page 1       | Questions Page 2 |
+----------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| Jim      | 'How are you?', 'Whats going on here?' | 'Whats going on here?' | 'How are you?'   |
| Joe      | 'Good and you?'                        |                        | 'Good and you?'  |
+----------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+
```